# Why isn't ImageMagick working in this script?

Tags: php, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm trying to make ImageMagick work in a PHP script. On the command-line, it works fine. I guessed it was maybe due to `convert` not being detected because ImageMagick is installed in the `C:\xampp` folder. What could be going wrong?

```
<?php
$path ='C:/xampp/';


$image ='_media/4055-Beckman-Lead-App/client/fpo.pdf';
$png ='_media/4055-Beckman-Lead-App/client/Capture.PNG';

if(file_exists($png)){

    echo $png;
    exec($path.'convert'. $png .'_media/4055-Beckman-Lead-App/client/fpo.png');
}
else {

    echo "file doesn't exist";
}
```

Comment: Getting an error message? Considered echoing out `$path.'convert'. $png .'_media/4055-Beckman-Lead-App/client/fpo.png'` and copy/pasting that in to your cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space between `convert` and the first PNG file name, and between the first and second PNG file names:

```
exec($path . 'convert ' . $png . ' _media/4055-Beckman-Lead-App/client/fpo.png');
```

The `.` operator in PHP just sticks two strings together, without adding extra space.

Comment: this is the command I type on is C:\xampp>convert C:\Users\dell-inspiron\Desktop\fpo.pdf  kudo.png and it works

Comment: @StackOverflow: I don't see what that comment has to do with my answer. Your posted code tries to run this command `C:/xampp/convert_media/4055-Beckman-Lead-App/client/Capture.PNG_media/4055-Beckman-Lead-App/client/fpo.png`. Do you see why it fails now, and why you need to add the spaces?